# jQuery addClass removed after reload the content

Tags: jquery

I used

```
$("select").addClass("dropdown")
```

to add 'dropdown' class on select box, but when the select box content refresh, above added class removed automatically.

Such as, when I select a country name, state options reloaded and when reloaded above added class is also removed.

How can I add class using jQuery, so it will stay even refreshed?

Comment: Probably there is an event function that is changing its class every time. There is too simple solutions: use `.change()` event to add the `dropdown` class again, or find what is resetting the select class and make it stop doing it. Post your code in JSFiddle so we can see it better

Comment: Where's the code that refreshes the select? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you want something to be kept after refresh you can't do it without saving state. You can try using cookies (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or localStorage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)